# Combine two tables based on a relationship table in Teradata

Tags: sql, join, teradata

Community,

I got the task to test data in Teradata. Coming from another field I would like to ask you for your help.

So I have three tables:

- `Zus0`: `ID1`, `ID2`
- `Zus1`: `ID1`
- `Zus2`: `ID2`

Now I need to join `Zus1` and `Zus2` based on `ID` information in `Zus0`.
The problem I got is that the `ID1` displayed in `Zus0` has another column name and format than in `Zus1`.

Like this:

- `ID1` in `Zus1`: "6123421"  ; --Column named IDZ
- `ID1` in `Zus0`: "000006123421";--Column named IDY

Now I want to join the two tables based on the relationship in `Zus0` do you know how I can do that?

Comment: What's the datatypes of both columns? Is there a chance of having other characters besides digits?

Comment: Will the column in `Zus0` always have leading 0s?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the IDs are all numeric and the issue is just the leading zeros in the ones that are stored as something like varchar:

```
SELECT b.id1, c.id2
FROM Zus0 a
INNER join Zus1 b on CAST(b.id1 as BIGINT)=CAST(a.id1 as BIGINT)
INNER join Zus2 c on CAST(c.id2 as BIGINT)=CAST(a.id2 as BIGINT)
```

You may not actually need to cast both sets of fields is one of them is already numeric.  Since you are casting the join will also be slower than it would be if both your fields were already numeric and no conversion was needed.

Comment: Actually, if you are doing this for testing:  The fact that the same info is stored differently should probably be a test fail.  Better to fix it now than to let something roll out like this